# Cannot bind to NSButton value in NSOutlineView

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, interface-builder

I have a classes, like this:

```
class OTF:NSObject {
var name:String = ""
var nameID:Int? = 0
var identifier:Int = 0
var isOn:Int! = 1
var search:Int = 0
var selected:Bool! = false

init(name:String, nameID:Int?, identifier:Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.nameID = nameID
    self.identifier = identifier

}}

class OTFeature:OTF {

var selDefault:Int?;
var parent:OTFType!

init (name:String, parent:OTFType, nameID:Int?, identifier:Int, selDefault:Int?) {
    super.init(name: name, nameID: nameID, identifier: identifier)
    self.selDefault = selDefault
    self.parent = parent
}}
```

When I bind (in Interface Builder) NSOutlineView `tableCellButton.objectValue.name` to title of NSButton placed inside NSTableCellView, my button has expected title: it's OK. Delegate and dataSource are working nice.

But if I want to bind `tableCellButton.ObjectValue.isOn` or `tableCellButton.objectValue.selected` to NSButton value I got an error:

`[<OTFReview.OTFeature 0x6180000e2b80> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key selected.`

Answer (score 1):

Your 'selected' property is optional so it can't be bound.
You need to make *selected* property non optional and initialize.
Also, you need to mention *selected* property as ***dynamic***.

Try code below and see what happen.

```
class
ViewController: NSViewController {

    dynamic var
    selected : Bool = false

    var
    x : Bool = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bind( "x", toObject: self, withKeyPath: "selected", options: nil )
        print( x )
    }
    @IBAction func
    Do( _: AnyObject ) {
        selected = !selected
        print( x )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! But why I need to bind **selected** to **x**?

Comment: It's just a sample. In your code, tableCellButton.ObjectValue.isOn is act as 'x'.

Comment: Oh, nice sample! Thank You!